# Python RegEx substitution of all but first instance found

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I've been fighting with this for a while and have simplified the problem down to this:
I am attempting to take a word like 'assessments' and substitute all 's' characters except the first instance found. IE as5e55ment5. It seems that re.sub() does all of the matching before calling the function retfun(). This seems counter to what is written in the PyDocs in Section 7.2 under re.sub(). My question is: Is there a different function I should be using that I've missed or is what I have below close and I'm just missing something obvious. Thanks! (Python 3.3.2)

```
    import re

    value = "assessments"
    inc = 0

    def retfun(num):
        global inc
        if num == 0:
            inc += 1
            return 's'
        else:
            return '5'

    nval = re.sub(r's', retfun(inc), value, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    print(nval)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class instead of function. Using function with global function, it will work only once if you don't clear the variable `inc`:

```
import re

class Replace:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
    def __call__(self, match):
        self.count += 1
        if self.count > 1:
            return '5'
        else:
            return match.group()

value = "assessments"
nval = re.sub(r's', Replace(), value, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(nval)
```

- The callback function takes a single match object argument.
- Instead of using hard-coded `s` in callback function, use `match.group()`.

**Alternative: nested function**

```
import itertools

def Replace():
    count = itertools.count()
    def wrapper(match):
        return '5' if next(count) > 0 else match.group()
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying...I'm trying to follow what you mean when you say 'it will work only once if you don't clear the variable inc." - Correct me if I'm wrong, but from how i understand it, because i am incrementing the global 'inc' variable it should keep track correct? I have adjusted the code above to clarify...

Comment: This is the solution I'm going with - just wanted to ask for one clarification regarding the match argument passed to wrapper. Does it somehow come from the re.sub() function? Is it an attribute of the 're' or the 'sub' object...if not where does it come from?

Comment: @user2680916, match object is come from the internal of `re.sub`.

Answer (score 0):

`retfun()` calls your function and returns the result. You need to pass your function:

```
nval = re.sub(r's', retfun, value, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Also, your replacement function should take a single argument:

```
def retfun(match):
```